# Can morning sex strengthen your immune system for the day?

Tags: sexuality, immune-system

http://www.womenshealthmag.com/sex-and-relationships/morning-sex

> Morning sex can strengthen your immune system for the day by enhancing your levels of IgA, an antibody that protects against infection.

Can morning sex strengthen your immune system for the day?

Comment: Paper critiquing the broader topic of popular articles citing sexual activity is healthy: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10912-010-9129-x

Answer (score 3):

The article you link to quotes [Debby Herbenick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debby_Herbenick) for this statement. There are studies showing the levels of [Immunoglobulin A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immunoglobulin_A) (IgA) are increased after morning exercise and [studies](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15217036) that indicate increased levels of IgA correlated with sexual activity.

IgA has been [shown](http://www.nature.com/mi/journal/v1/n1/full/mi20076a.html) to be vital in mucosal immunity.

> In general, immunization or infection at mucous membranes resulted in high titer of protective antibodies at the mucosal site with absent or low titers in serum, whereas the reverse occurred with parenteral immunization.

Source: [Mucosal Immunology (2008)](http://www.nature.com/mi/journal/v1/n1/full/mi20076a.html)

Supporting the claim by Debby Herbenick, [a study by Carl Charnetski and Francis Brennan](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15217036) showed a positive correlation between higher sexual activity and IgA levels in college students. Noting:

> Individuals in the frequent group showed significantly higher levels
>   of IgA than the other three groups, which were comparable

(source: Psychol [Rep. 2004 Jun;94(3 Pt 1):839-44.4](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15217036))

Finally, there have been studies on the effects on the immune system in the broader category of physical exercise too. The positive effects found from such exercise indicate that the source effect is not purely from sex, but either additive or interactive with the effect from generic physical activity.

> Findings indicated that long and intensive exercises weaken the
>   immune system, while moderate and short drills strengthened this
>   system.

Source: [Asian J Sports Med. Sep 2012; 3(3): 185–192.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3445646/)

Therefore, it seems fair to assume a positive effect on IgA levels from morning sex. Based on the study by Hejazi and Hosseini, I'd advise the 'short drill' version to avoid an inadvertent negative effect stemming from endurance exercise.

Comment: The first statement reads like an argument by authority, maybe you can avoid it?

Comment: I'll trust that readers will find it out for themselves. It was more to show that it's not just 'one of those' type of statements, avoiding the bias of non-authority. But I see what you mean.

Comment: This answer is a bit theoretical. It also seems to suggest that it is the confounding factor of exercise rather than sexual intercourse itself that has the effect.

Comment: It merely notes the presence of the confounding factor. The question would still be answered if it was purely due to physical exercise. Hmmm... I'm not opposed to making this answer more practical. But a photoshoot doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: The study you mention by Herbenick seems contradictory. Only those who had sex 1-2 times per week had higher IgA levels. Those who had sex 3+ times did not. I would submit the results, therefore, are not reliable enough to base any claims on them.

Comment: @Oddthinking Exercise is not a confounding factor. It is part of the causal chain. If exercise is the mechanism by which sex boosts the immune system, that does not weaken the claim.